# Draw lines on bing map with different colors

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

I want to draw two lines (directions) on a bing map but I want each direction line to be in a different color. Is there a way to set the line color?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, this is really easy. When you create a polyline you can set options on it. One of them is the stroke color. Here is a simple code sample to make a polyline that's blue:

```
var line = new Microsoft.Maps.Polyline([your points],  {strokeColor: new Microsoft.Maps.Color(150,0,0 255)});
```

You can find documentation for the polyline class and options here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427597.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427595.aspx

You can also find some samples on the Bing Maps interactive SDK here:

https://www.bingmapsportal.com/ISDK/AjaxV7#Shapes2

Comment: how to set the color for the "directionManager.CalculateDirections" method. this is the one that I am using and I need to set the color

Comment: On the DirectionManager class, you have the setRenderOptions() method which can take an object of type DirectionRenderOptions as a parameter, see the MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh312832.aspx On Which you can set the corresponding polylineOptions (depending on the route mode)